# Pop index is out of range when testing the array while removing an item at each iteration

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to solve the almost increasing sequence problem.  The goal is to see if an array is a strictly increasing sequence if no more than one item is removed.  I'm trying to accomplish this with the `pop()` method.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
    new_seq = sequence

    output = False

    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        new_seq.pop(i)
        if all(i < j for i, j in zip(new_seq, new_seq[1:])):
            output = True
        else:
            output = False

    return output
```

I'm basically popping the element at index i and then assigning a boolean value to `output` depending on whether it is strictly increasing or not but this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  main.py3 in the pre-written template, in getUserOutputs
    userOutput = _runmaxat(testInputs[i])
  main.py3 in the pre-written template, in _runmaxat
    return almostIncreasingSequence(*_fArgs_mksftvlwcpxn)
  main.py3 on line 6, in almostIncreasingSequence
    sequence.pop(i)
IndexError: pop index out of range
Sample tests: 0/19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you pop, it alters the list and your index no longer points where you'd expect.

Example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
count = 0

for i in a:
    print('Count ', str(count))
    print(i)
    a.pop()
    print(i)
    count += 1

'''
('Count ', '0')
1
3
1
('Count ', '1')
2
2
2
'''
```

If you want to traverse a list without losing order, simply create a copy of "a" when performing the for loop:

```
a = [1,2,3]
count = 0

for i in list(a):
    print('Count ', str(count))
    print(i)
    a.pop()
    print(i)
    count += 1

'''
('Count ', '0')
1
3
1
('Count ', '1')
2
2
2
('Count ', '2')
3
1
3
'''
```

Comment: Your example doesn't really show the issue with this. The code and output you posted seem to demonstrate a valid behaviour. Also, what is the purpose of `count`?

Comment: Thanks, forgot to update count. I've edited my answer to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: Again, this doesn't seem to pose any issue. The problem in the OP code is that the loop is iterating on the indexes of the original list and then trying to access elements that no longer exist. Your example loops on elements which gives a different effect

Comment: Just implemented your suggestion and still doesn't work.

Comment: @OnurOzbek What error is it throwing now?

Comment: The same error.  Check my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = [1, 2, 3]
while foo:
    print(foo)
    foo.pop()
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
3
[1, 2]
2
[1]
1
```